# ImageIcon displaying only description and not Image

Tags: java, swing

When I try to display ImageIcon in JTable only description is rendered.The code is:

```
 private void createTable() {
   dataModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
   @Override
   public int getColumnCount() { return 10; }
   @Override
   public int getRowCount() { return 10;}
   @Override
   public ImageIcon getValueAt(int row, int col) { 
   icon=new ImageIcon();
   icon=createImageIcon("..\\studentimages\\img0.png","angry");  //method to render url of image
  // STUDENT_IMG_LBL=new JLabel(icon);
  return icon ;
   }
  };
  }
```

Comment: which editor you'r using netbeans, eclipse etc.

Comment: Could it be that the ImageIcon don't have time to load the image (assuming it can load the image) before it renders? Could you try creating the ImageIcon only once and reuse it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to return the ImageIcon as column class. If it doesn't help define your own Renderer extending DefaultTableCellRenderer and set the icon to the renderer.

Comment: returning the correct column class will help, no need for a custom renderer :-)

Comment: @kleopatra i have verified that object is returned to the correct column.

Comment: @xyz - read the answer carefully, then the api of TableModel (hint: column _class_ is the important part)

Comment: @xyz no problem :-) Did you succeed?